# repackage xenial .deb for bionic

Tags: python, openstack, deb, cisco

I have a set of .deb files which I downloaded from Cisco to use in Openstack.  The problem is that packages are for Openstack Queens (Ubuntu 16.04 w/python v2.7 ) and I'm running Openstack Stein (Ubuntu 18.04 w/python v3.x).

I was wondering, is there a way to upgrade&repackage them, making them fit into Ubuntu 18.04 without too much hustle? I know of someone who did it but they haven't said how exactly. I can surely unpack the .deb and see what's inside, but not sure what I should do with that after.

As an alternative I see go round the github and download respective plugins (I already found few of them, but not everything).

Thank you for any help,
Kind regards,

Comment: http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/  is the Ubuntu packaging guide.  Even Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has `python` call python 2.7, and `python3` called python 3.x, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: python2.7 is going to be end of life effective next year. I didn't find any markers that would port it to a specific python version. I thought there will be something checking the version of the system these modules are running on. is it not something that is defined in these files? Thanks

Comment: Migrating from Python2 to Python3 might be easy...or might be hard. Py3 had many changes, and is NOT backward-compatible with Py2. Seems to be highly unlikely to be a simple version-bump-and-repackage Somebody (at Cisco) may need to sit down and spend a week or two updating and testing. Impossible to tell from the question, sorry,

Comment: Canonical will support `python` (2.7) until releases reach EOL.  Ubuntu has progressively moving away from python 2.7 and to 3.x for years, however both 16.04 & 18.04 have `python` mean 2.7, and `python3` meaning 3.x. (3.7.4 for my release). Enter `python -V` on your system (my 19.10 reports 2.7.16+, and I get 2.7.15+ on a 18.04.3 system)

Comment: Got it. Thank you all. 
On my system I'm running Python 2.7.15+. In short it means I don't have to worry about python 2.7 EOL just yet and since I haven't found any environment markers in the installation plugins it should be okay to run installation of xenial (latest) plugin packages on bionic.